# Libreoffice launches CSV window set to UTF-16 on UTF-8 file

Tags: utf-8, fedora, libreoffice, utf-16

Just installed Fedora 24 (Mate Spin).   When LibreOffice 5 is directed to open a CSV, the dropdown is set to utf16.  How can I set the dropdown to default as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to set the default file encoding for LibreOffice.  If you know the settings ahead of time, then it should be possible to write a macro to do it.

As an example, my solution for saving in UTF-8 is at https://superuser.com/a/1102494/541756.